# How many variables can pyscipopt handle?/ How to deal with Warning: getSolObjVal cannot only be called in stage SOLVING without a valid solution?

Tags: python, optimization, linear-programming

I am building a transportation optimization model with pyscipopt. It works on a small subset of the data but when I try to run the entire dataset the model throws this error when I use model.getObjVal():

Warning: getSolObjVal cannot only be called in stage SOLVING without a valid solution (current stage: 10)

I am trying to allocate ~about 80,000 customers to 90 branches while minimizing total distance and subjecting to branch size constraints.

If the dataset is too big, are there any other ways that can solve my problem? Thank you!!

Update:
The warning shows up at stage 10 (SCIP_STAGE_SOLVED = 10, /**< the problem was solved */)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ks4kO.png)

Comment: You may want to show the solver log.

Answer (score 0):

This error is clearly not indicating that the model is too large - you are most likely querying the solution value before the solver is finished.

Stage 6 is `STAGE_EXITPRESOLVE`. [See this page for all status codes](https://www.scipopt.org/doc/html/type__set_8h_source.php#l00033).

There is no proper limit for the number of variables you can add - you will run into all kinds of issues before reaching a number that exceeds some internal indexing limits. Let alone solving such a huge model will be hard, to say the least.